# HTML CSS divide table cells

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to divide cells in 24 segments/hours.
Here is my approach:

[My approach](https://jsfiddle.net/17tbk28a/1/)
I have divided the cell(s) in 24 segments, but the result is not really appropriate:

```
<td class="tdFirst">
        <div class="personalHourFieldWrapper">
            <div class="personalHourField" style="left:4.12%;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="personalHourField" style="left:8.24%;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="personalHourField" style="left:12.36%;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="personalHourField" style="left:16.48%;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Actually I don't know how to order the separator lines side by side.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Use of float: left or display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You just need to add

```
td div {
    float: left
}
```

in your styles. This will make all the `div` elements align horizontally.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/17tbk28a/3/)

```css
.tdFirst {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.tdFirst .personalHourFieldWrapper div {
  border-right: 1px dotted #666;
  width: 3.9%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1px solid #000">
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Thusday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdFirst">
      <div class="personalHourFieldWrapper">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` works here too, and you don't even have to do any calculations for the widths.

```css
.tdFirst {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.tdFirst .personalHourFieldWrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.tdFirst .personalHourFieldWrapper div {
  border-right: 1px dotted #666;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1px solid #000">
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdFirst">
      <div class="personalHourFieldWrapper">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```